# How to calculate the following Jacobian on Lie group SO(3)?

Tags: bspline, slam-algorithm

everyone, I've met a problem to calculate the following question(see https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2020/papers/Sommer_Efficient_Derivative_Computation_for_Cumulative_B-Splines_on_Lie_Groups_CVPR_2020_paper.pdf):
The partial differential is:
[image: SO(3) partial with respect to vector]
I've tried to calculate this but it seems that the result does not coincide with the code which contains in so3_spline.h of basalt:

```html
J_helper = coeff[i + 1] * res.matrix() * Jl_k_delta * Jl_inv_delta * p0.inverse().matrix();
```

Does anyone know the reasons?

Comment: https://paperswithcode.com/paper/efficient-derivative-computation-for perhaps this might help

Comment: @ jspcal, thank you for your kind reply. I've tried but seems not coincide with...